# Getting index of a key in a Hashtable in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, key, hashtable

I am writing an implementation of a Dictionary class. I am currently writing the add method

(public V **add** (K key, V value))

Algorithm:

```
if the table is too full
    rehash
grab the index based on the key
probe with the index and key to resolve collisions
if the table at the index is null, or has been removed
    increment the number of entries
    increment the number of locations used
    set the table at that index to a new tableentry
else
    grab the value currently at that index
    set the value at the index to the new value
return the old value
```

I can't figure out how to grab the index based on the key provided. I also don't know how to refer to a specific index in a Hashtable.

Thanks

Comment: Every Java object has a `hashCode()` method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode() .  If you intend to use your object as a key in a hash table then you should overwrite _both_ this method _and_ the `equals(Object)` method.

Comment: The index into the hash table depends on the hash function along with the hash code of each key.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are re-implementing a Dictionary/Hashtable from scratch for whatever reason (if you're not, and *use* a Hashtable - then the algorithm you're citing is completely out of place).

The classic approach when implementing an array-backed hashtable is to calculate the hash of the key, and then put the value in the array index of that key modulus the array size (after accounting for collisions in whatever way).

So, "grab the index based on the key" would be `index = hash(key) % backing_array_length;`.